# Power BI Or SQL function for iterating through rows, finding null in cell and then deleting all rows with same identifier

Tags: t-sql, data-cleaning, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to find the best way to clean my data using either T-SQL or a tool within Power BI.
included is a snippet of my data, I would usually do this in Excel using multiple tables & VLOOKUP however my data set contains 2+ million Rows so this isn't an option.
I need a function that:

1. Iterates through each row looking at each 'SiteID'
2. checks related 'flow' value for 'NULL' or '0'
3. If 'NULL' or '0'  finds all the rest of the 'SiteID's' with the same value in the full data set in the rows above or below
4. Removes all rows with matching 'ID'S' Regardless  if any other 'null' or actual value exists
5. Moves onto next record checking same & continuing iteration of complete data set

is this something which is possible? thanks for any advice or help :)
[Sample data values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkulQ.png)

Comment: yes, it's possible, I think you should be use dynamic sql to do that job. I'll add a sample query for your question later.

Comment: There are several approaches.  You could group the rows together by `SiteID` and see if `Max( flow ) is not NULL`. Or use `not exists` to reduce the dataset, e.g. `select * from UnspecifiedTable as UT where not exists ( select 42 from UnspecifiedTable as UTI where UTI.SiteId = UT.SiteId and UTI.flow is NULL );`. Have a go and let us know if there is a specific problem.  In any event, you want to think in terms of _sets_, not iterating through row by (agonizing) row.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another thing, if you have a million rows of data, iteration is not a good option to think about. I guess all you want is to remove records having Null or 0 in flow. I perfer to use CTE just to be clear in logic.

```
    ;WITH deletion AS
    (
    SELECT SiteID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Flow = 0 or Flow is null
    )
    DELETE T
    FROM Table1 T
    INNER JOIN Deletion D on T.SiteID = D.SIteID
```